# Tesseract traineddata not working in Swift 3.0 project using version 4.0

Tags: ios, swift, ocr, tesseract

I'm attempting to use [Tesseract-OCR-iOS](https://github.com/gali8/Tesseract-OCR-iOS) in a new Swift 3.0 project. I'm using Xcode Version 8.1 (8B62). CocoaPods is version 1.1.1.

When I attempt to use `tesseract.recognize()`, my app crashes and I get the following output in the console:

```
actual_tessdata_num_entries_ <= TESSDATA_NUM_ENTRIES:Error:Assert failed:in file tessdatamanager.cpp, line 53
```

I found [this post](https://github.com/tesseract-ocr/tesseract/wiki/FAQ#actual_tessdata_num_entries_-tessdata_num_entrieserrorassert-failedin-file-ccutiltessdatamanagercpp-line-55_), which sounds I'm using the wrong version of `traineddata`. I downloaded `tessdata` from [the tesseract-ocr/tessdata repo](https://github.com/tesseract-ocr/tessdata), so I'm baffled as to why I'd have a mismatch on the version numbers.

Any suggestions how to get Tesseract working are greatly appreciated. Below is additional information re: my setup.

Here's what my `Podfile` looks like:

```
# Uncomment the next line to define a global platform for your project
platform :ios, '9.0'

target 'TesseractDemo' do
  # Comment the next line if you're not using Swift and don't want to use dynamic frameworks
  use_frameworks!

  # Pods for TesseractDemo
pod 'TesseractOCRiOS', '4.0.0'

end
```

I've dragged a `tessdata` folder containing `eng.traineddata` into the root directory of my project outside of Xcode and dragged a **reference** from Finder to Xcode's Project Navigator.

Everything works fine up to this point. No compiler errors, linker whining, etc. In a `UIViewController` I'm importing `TesseratOCR` and calling it like so:

```
// MARK: - OCR Methods
func scanImage(image: UIImage) {
    if let tesseract = G8Tesseract(language: "eng") {
        tesseract.delegate = self
        tesseract.image = imageToScan?.g8_blackAndWhite()
        tesseract.recognize()

        textView.text = tesseract.recognizedText
    }
}
```

**Update**
I found a link to a [repo of traineddata files for **version 4.0**](https://github.com/tesseract-ocr/tesseract/wiki/Data-Files#data-files-for-version-400). I nuked my old eng.traineddata file and replaced it with the one from the 4.0 repo. I get the same error referencing the same line.

Comment: Hello, we're you able to find the right .traineddata file?

Comment: used version 4.0 but still got the same error in same line

Answer (score 44, accepted):

The current version of `eng.traineddata` linked above on GitHub will not work with the current version of the [Tesseract-OCR-iOS](https://github.com/gali8/Tesseract-OCR-iOS).

The installation instructions posted on GitHub work perfectly if you've got the right `<language>.traineddata` file.

I discovered this after dragging the `eng.traineddata` from [Lyndsey Scott's brilliant Tesseract tutorial on Ray Wenderlich](https://www.raywenderlich.com/93276/implementing-tesseract-ocr-ios).

[This repo](https://github.com/tesseract-ocr/tessdata/tree/bf82613055ebc6e63d9e3b438a5c234bfd638c93) contains the `eng.traineddata` file I needed to get Tesseract working. I'm not sure if that applies to all languages.

Comment: Also works with Croatian so I presume it'll work with other languages too. Thanks Adrian !

Comment: can we install tessdata from pod ?

Comment: This is awesome!

Comment: Thanks for saving approximately 2 hours 27 minutes of my life.

Answer (score -1):

I had the same problem yesterday, Ithink the problem is with the dictionary, I just change the dictionary of github for the  "Lyndsey Scott's brilliant Tesseract tutorial on Ray Wenderlich" dictionary (posted lines before)and it works very well.
I have xcode 9.4.1 and it recognize the lyndsey file in a different way than the github file