# Taking a photo and using TesseractOCR

Tags: ios, swift, tesseract

So I want to take a picture of some text, but when using tesseract it gives me the following error:

> actual_tessdata_num_entries_ <= TESSDATA_NUM_ENTRIES:Error:Assert
>   failed:in file tessdatamanager.cpp, line 53

so when `ViewController1` captures a picture it sends it to the `TextViewController` like this:

send from `ViewController1`:

```
extension CameraViewController: AVCapturePhotoCaptureDelegate {
    func photoOutput(_ output: AVCapturePhotoOutput, didFinishProcessingPhoto photo: AVCapturePhoto, error: Error?) {
        if let imageData = photo.fileDataRepresentation() {
            self.image = UIImage(data: imageData)
            let text = TextViewController()
            text.image = self.image
            self.present(text, animated: true, completion: nil)
        }
    }
}
```

And it should receive like this in `TextViewController()` and display on `textView`, but it just crashes:

```
@IBOutlet weak var textView: UITextView!
    var image: UIImage?

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        if let tesseract = G8Tesseract(language: "eng") {
            tesseract.delegate = self
            tesseract.image = self.image
            tesseract.recognize()

            textView.text = tesseract.recognizedText
        }
}
```

Comment: How do you know that the view controller has an image when it tries to read it with viewDidLoad?

Comment: yeah that was meant to be in view will appear @ElTomato

Answer (score 1):

Actually, That error is nothing to do with your code. The .traineddata you linked in your code is not working with current version of [Tesseract-OCR-iOS](https://github.com/gali8/Tesseract-OCR-iOS).

Because `pod 'TesseractOCRiOS', '4.0.0'` runs with tesseract engine version 3.03-rc1. If you are using the latest traineddata files from the source [tessdata](https://github.com/tesseract-ocr/tessdata), it only works with Tesseract 4.0.0 not with 3.03-rc1.

If you want to use only eng.traineddata, you can check the solution[here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41131083/tesseract-traineddata-not-working-in-swift-3-0-project-using-version-4-0/41168236#41168236). The other option is to train [lang].traineddata yourself and tesseract is fully trainable. If you want, you can check [tesseract training process](https://github.com/tesseract-ocr/tesseract/wiki/TrainingTesseract).